# Why do companies make up an unknown skill to reject a candidate?

Tags: interviewing

**Summary:**

Why do companies make up an unknown skill to reject a candidate?

**Long version:**

The job application process goes like this: a recruiter submits me for a software developer position with a company. I have a good phone interview with the HR manager, I get an in-person interview with the department manager and lead developer, I do well on their technical test, and everything seems to go well. They talk about my skills and I explain how my experience will fit the position.

Then a few days later, the recruiter calls me back to say the department manager now wants "multi-media experience", which they never mentioned during the interview process. I also had a good interview process with "Hilton Hotels" (not their real name) and they later said they wanted someone with "entrepreneurial experience", which again, they never mentioned before, any time during the interview process. And this time, the recruiter said this completely caught her by surprised because they never mentioned it to her either!

The issue is: if these skills were so important that they're rejecting me because I don't have them, how come no one mentioned it to the recruiter before the interview process? And how come no one on the team, mentioned it *at any point during the interview process*?

This happened to me three times, and in two of those cases, the recruiter said the manager never mentioned these skills to her!

My question is: is rejecting a person for having a skill that was never mentioned actually a real reason for rejecting a candidate? Or is there something else, that the manager can't say, such as they won't hire me because I'm a white male and they're looking for diversity? Or the opposite- perhaps during the in-person interview, they saw that I'm a black woman and they think I can't do the same job as a white male? Obviously, it's illegal to discriminate like this, but it's perfectly legal to claim someone has a missing skill that was never brought up during the interview process.

But if a company doesn't want me, why not use the standard generic response of "We're looking at candidates whose experience better fits the position."?

And is there anything I can do to overcome this kind of objection? Or is there nothing I can do, since I don't know what skill that's not on my resume, they'll ask about?

Comment: Question: Is this the same recruiter every time? Then there's something off.

Comment: It's very likely bad luck, your sample size is 3 and that's the first time I ever hear about that despite all my interviews.

Comment: Who can say? They might be running a beauty contest for candidates, and the reasons for rejection are genuine despite being spurious. Or they might be concealing something unacceptable behind a fabricated reason. Or maybe they have another candidate who they are proceeding with because they have found that he has the skill they say you are missing, and it wasn't until the interview that they realised they needed that skill or that they could get it at the price they were willing to pay.

Comment: We can't be sure. All we know is they did not want you on that day.

Comment: There may be an internal candidate that is already groomed for the job, but company policy requires an outside search; if this is the USA, there could be an internal H1B candidate for the job, but the law requires proving that no US Americans can fill the position, there could be an identical copy of you out there and the hiring manager needs a reason to discriminate...

Comment: **Is there anything I can do to overcome this kind of objection?** - They can reject you for any reason, or for no reason, so long as the reason isn't legally prohibited, which they would never admit to. So at the end of the day, there isn't anything you can do.

Comment: A variant of this I've seen _a lot_: I apply for a job; the application deadline passes; I don't get the job and neither does anyone else, i.e. the position is not successfully filled; a few weeks later, the vacancy is re-advertised with two or three extra, very specialised "essential requirements" added to the person specification.

Comment: After the scenario where there was an unofficial "favorite" candidate, the next most common thing, IMO, might be that the manager or team simply wants someone who "speaks their language" ... an informal requirement of rapport, feelings of trust, comfort, loyalty, etc. These can be awkward to specify in detail, plus historically have been used as an excuse for discrimination, so modern corporate culture frowns upon trying to do so... so some other formal excuse is made up, when the intangibles are not there

Comment: @DanielHatton When you see something like that they already had the person they wanted picked out, the job offer was just to comply with either internal or legal requirements.

Comment: I've seen it happen at my old company and it was simply due to bad communication in the company and them not being able to agree on what they want to begin with. Eventually it gets past the interviews and one person says 'actually we really need someone with this experience as well', or priorities change, or one person they interviewed had this experience in addition which made them realise they could use that experience.

Comment: To answer some questions:
It's different recruiters with different client companies.
I understand companies can use any legal reason to reject someone, but my question is why make a missing skill when they can easily use a vague excuse like "We found a stronger candidate"?

Comment: Maybe they just didnt like you or your skill? I dont know, I feel like it has become normal to not tell people why they got rejected. I had marvellous interviews where people basically said "here you will be working and what kind of software do you want? We get everything set up" or interviews where they didnt ask me ONE question but only talked about how great their company is and why I NEED to work there. Hell even got interviews that ended with "we will send you the contract ASAP". 
All of them basically ghosted me or sent a normal rejection "it is not you, its us" kinda way. Just move on

Answer (score 11):

> Why do companies make up an unknown skill to reject a candidate?

They don't, there is no reason why they would when they can just reject you with no reason.

Perhaps they found another candidate with that skillset, or they were just going through the motions. Either way there's no point doing more than writing it off to experience and focusing on other job opportunities.

Comment: "when they can just reject you with no reason" ... At least in the US, some larger companies and governments do have have a formal process designed to prevent arbitrary decisions, if only to prevent the company/org/gov from being accused of discrimination based on gender, race, or favoritism, nepotism, etc. So it's not unheard of that some nominal reason is found and documented, to superficially satisfy requirements of the process.

Comment: My money's on the beginning of the second paragraph here. Employers rarely do anything as dramatic as "rejecting" a candidate - they just choose someone else.

Answer (score 6):

> is rejecting a person for having a skill that was never mentioned actually a real reason for rejecting a candidate?

It could be a “real” reason in the sense that they have too many qualified candidates and as a result are narrowing their selection criteria. They probably had a long list of “nice to haves” in their head that weren’t mentioned to this recruiter. It’s possible they met with other candidates after you who had everything you had plus multimedia skills, entrepreneurial skills, tap dancing skills, etc.

It could also have something to do with age, gender, race, sexual orientation but I agree that if this were the case, they wouldn’t go back to the recruiter with a list of specific additional qualifications. To me this sounds like a case of “We’ve found better candidates through other recruiters so if you want to be the one to fill this position, you need to raise the bar.”

> Or is there nothing I can do, since I don't know what skill that's not on my resume, they'll ask about?

At the end of the interview, you can ask “Do you have any concerns about my ability to succeed in this role that I might be able to address?” Some people won’t feel comfortable answering this type of question and you sort of have to read the room to decide whether or not it’s appropriate. On the other hand, some might see it as an invitation to speak candidly about what they’re really thinking.

For example, they might say, “well, we really want someone with devops experience and from what I see here, you’ve only done pure development.” This gives you an opportunity to say, “actually, I’m in charge of maintaining several AWS pipelines at my current company and have also used Kubernetes for some of my personal projects. It’s given me an appreciation for how different design decisions can enable or inhibit new features to be quickly integrated and deployed to production.” If the interviewer is really forthcoming, they might even touch on something more subjective. “Your technical abilities are solid but it seems like you’re used to working on solo projects. We really need someone who’s a team player.”  You could address this, either by citing examples of times you’ve had to work closely with others or if the interviewer is right, talk about why you’re tired of working in isolation and are looking for a change.

This won’t help if they actually have other candidates with experience they want that you don’t have but you should certainly give them as many of your selling points as possible. Catering your resume to the job description is a good practice but you should also include anything tangentially related to the listed requirements as well as anything that relates to the company in general.

This advice is very general and it doesn’t explain why you didn’t get this particular job or what you could have done differently. It could’ve been anything from the firmness of your handshake to the color shoes you wore. To quote Jean-Luc Paccard, "It is possible to commit no mistakes and still lose. That is not a weakness; that is life." As a data scientist, I’ve learned to not try to infer too much from any one data point but instead to look for larger patterns. If you get rejected for a role you believe you were qualified for not just once but maybe three or four or five times in a row, then it would make sense to ask, “what am I doing wrong and what can I do differently?” For this one instance, I would write it off as a glitch in the simulation and move on.

Answer (score 1):

> is rejecting a person for having a skill that was never mentioned actually a real reason for rejecting a candidate?

Typically not. It occasionally happens that during an interview the hiring manager realizes that there is something that's missing from the job description, but it's rare.

> Obviously, it's illegal to discriminate like this, but it's perfectly legal to claim someone has a missing skill that was never brought up during the interview process.

Correct. But that would only apply if you are in a protected class in your location

> This happened to me three times, and in two of those cases, the recruiter said the manager never mentioned these skills to her!

That is indeed odd (on multiple levels). First things first: you are tanking the interviews. Your resume is apparently fine (otherwise you wouldn't get interviews) but either something in your resume doesn't match up with your actual experience/skill or there are problems with your behavior during the interview. I recommend doing some practice interviews with a coach or trusted friend or peer who is good at this.

The odd part is that they would give this excuse and even answer your follow up question. This may be a culture thing in your location and/or industry. Or you are indeed in a protected class and the company wants to put as much legal protection in the rejection as possible.

Regardless of what the reason is, you should try to work on your interview skills and/or try to understand the real reason for the rejection. The wording of the rejection doesn't really matter: look forward, nit backward.

Comment: "You are tanking the interviews". That's a possibility and I tried to think about what I may have said or done. But in 2 out of the 3 times, the recruiter started the conversation with "You had a great interview and they think you'd make a great fit, but they're looking for this skill they never mentioned". So then the question is whether I actually tanked the interview and company is being polite or if they really did "forget" the other skill.

Comment: Sorry, but chances are they are just being polite. "new skill" is not very likely